# How to post something to Instagram without the app?

Tags: instagram

How can I post something to Instagram without downloading the app?

Answer (score 3):

You can login to [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en) website using any browser from your computer or mobile and post whatever you want post. You don't need to download app.